# Are there any other books contemporary to the Old Testament early books?

Tags: hebrew-bible

Are there any other books written in the Hebrew contemporary to the books from Genesis to the Second Chronicles and the book of Job, or all these books is all we have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other books mentioned in the Hebrew scriptures from Genesis to Chronicles, some are available today which were composed during the Hebraic period. The Hebrew scriptures mentions a number of ancient written works, alongside the authoritative books. Some of them not all is listed below;

**Book of the Covenant**

> And he took **the book of the covenant**, and read in the audience of the
> people: and they said, All that the Lord hath said will we do, and be
> obedient. **(Exodus 24:7 KJV)**

**Book of the Wars of the Lord**

> Wherefore it is said in **the book of the wars of the Lord**, What he did
> in the Red sea, and in the brooks of Arnon. **(Numbers 21:14 KJV)**

**Book of Jasher (Available)**

> And the sun stood still, and the moon stayed, until the people had
> avenged themselves upon their enemies. Is not this written in **the
> book of Jasher**? So the sun stood still in the midst of heaven, and
> hasted not to go down about a whole day. **(Joshua 10:13 KJV)**

> (Also he bade them teach the children of Judah the use of the bow: behold, it is written in **the book of Jasher**.) **(2 Samuel 1:18 KJV)**

**The Manner of the Kingdom / Book of Statutes**

> Then Samuel told the people the manner of the kingdom, and wrote it in
> a book, and laid it up before the Lord. And Samuel sent all the people
> away, every man to his house. **(1 Samuel 10:25 KJV)**

**Book of Samuel the Seer (Available)**

> Now the acts of David the king, first and last, behold, they are
> written in the book of **Samuel the seer**, and in the book of Nathan the
> prophet, and in the book of Gad the seer, **(1 Chronicles 29:29 KJV)**

**The book of Nathan the Prophet (Available)**

> Now the acts of David the king, first and last, behold, they are
> written in the book of Samuel the seer, and in **the book of Nathan** the
> prophet, and in the book of Gad the seer, **(1 Chronicles 29:29 KJV)**

**Gad the seer (Available)**

> Now the acts of David the king, first and last, behold, they are
> written in the book of Samuel the seer, and in the book of Nathan the
> prophet, and in **the book of Gad the seer**, **(1 Chronicles 29:29 KJV)**

**The Acts of Solomon**

> And the rest of the acts of Solomon, and all that he did, and his
> wisdom, are they not written in the book of **the acts of Solomon**? **(1
> Kings 11:41 KJV)**

**Shemaiah the Prophet**

> Now the acts of Rehoboam, first and last, are they not written in
> **the book of Shemaiah the prophet**, and of Iddo the seer concerning genealogies? And there were wars between Rehoboam and Jeroboam
> continually. **(2 Chronicles 12:15 KJV)**

**Story of Prophet Iddo**

> And the rest of the acts of Abijah, and his ways, and his sayings, are
> written in **the story of the prophet Idd**o. **(2 Chronicles 13:22 KJV)**

**Book of Jehu**

> Now the rest of the acts of Jehoshaphat, first and last, behold, they
> are written in t**he book of Jehu** the son of Hanani, who is
> mentioned in the book of the kings of Israel. **(2 Chronicles 20:34 KJV**

**Sayings of the Seers  Here**

> His prayer also, and how God was intreated of him, and all his sins,
> and his trespass, and the places wherein he built high places, and set
> up groves and graven images, before he was humbled: behold, they are
> written among **the sayings of the seers**. **(2 Chronicles 33:19
> KJV)**

Comment: It's more than likely a few of these refer to books found in Scripture under later names. For example, Solomon traditionally wrote Proverbs etc. before this book, and so 'all that Solomon did is written in the acts of Solomon' could refer to a scroll containing all his books, for example. Just throwing that out there.

Comment: Thank you. Can you, please, add which of these books are available today?

Comment: @SolaGratia Thank you for shearing your insight, I did not so as same book different names.

Comment: @brilliant Brate I wrote (Available) on those that can be found today but they might not be genuin.